# Logj4j2.xml Schema Errors

Tags: xsd, schema, log4j2

I'm having trouble getting my log4j2.xml file to conform to the schema.  Without the schema specification I don't have any errors but with it in place I am getting:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'File'. No child element is expected at 
 this point.

cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Logger'. No child element is expected 
 at this point.
```

The logging works fine without the schema but Eclipse is warning that its missing so I would like to have it in place.  This is the log4j2.xml file I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration strict="true"
           xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config 
           https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/logging-log4j2/log4j-2.11.1/log4j-core/src/main/resources/Log4j-config.xsd">

  <Appenders>

    <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z} %-5p %-5level - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>

    <File name="file" fileName="mylogfile.log" append="true">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z} %-5p %-5level - %msg%n"/>
    </File >
  </Appenders>


  <Loggers>
    <Root level="DEBUG">
      <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
    </Root>

    <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="WARN" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="net.authorize.util" level="WARN" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="net.authorize.api" level="WARN" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
    </Logger>

  </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the schema as defined [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/logging-log4j2/log4j-2.11.1/log4j-core/src/main/resources/Log4j-config.xsd)

1. Does not have an Appender called File defined, did you meant to use Layout under an Appender node?  Although strangely enough, their example [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) shows them using  after the Console node.
2. Defines that the Root node occurs after all the Logger nodes

Sample file that will validate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration strict="true"
           xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config 
           https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/logging-log4j2/log4j-2.11.1/log4j-core/src/main/resources/Log4j-config.xsd">

    <Appenders>

        <Appender type="file" name="" fileName="mylogfile.log">
            <Layout type="">                    
                <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z} %-5p %-5level - %msg%n</Pattern>
            </Layout>
        </Appender>

        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z} %-5p %-5level - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>


    </Appenders>


    <Loggers>

        <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="WARN" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="net.authorize.util" level="WARN" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="net.authorize.api" level="WARN" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Logger>

        <Root level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
        </Root>


    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Comment: Awesome.  Even the log4j developers had problems.  Thanks.

Comment: @zappullae There is a comment part way through their page "Add the JmDns library from http://jmdns.sourceforge.net to the application classpath"   I'm maybe they updated that schema in there?